# Unable to make classification(Sentiment analysis) after pickling (XXX.h5)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I Have created Lstm Model for sentiment analysis. The model is predicting fine before saving it to XXX.h5. I am saving the using the following codes:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model.save('XXX.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'XXX.h5'
```

Now, I am trying to load the model using following code:

```
model1 = load_model('XXX.h5')
```

The model is being loaded successfully. I want sentiment analysis on the new statement that is written as shown in below codes

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import load_model 
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import numpy as np

X = ['he is a good person'] 

texts = X
vocabSize = 2000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocabSize, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
model1 = load_model('XXX.h5')
#vectorizing the tweet by the pre-fitted tokenizer instance
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
#padding the tweet to have exactly the same shape as `embedding_2` input
X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=28, dtype='int32', value=0)
#print(X)
sentiment = model1.predict(X,batch_size=1,verbose = 2)[0]
if(np.argmax(sentiment) == 0):
    print("negative")
elif (np.argmax(sentiment) == 1):
    print("positive")
```

The Result is restricted to only positive and Negative In this case but I get negative as the answer irrespective of the sentence. I want The above sentence to be predicted as positive.

where did I go wrong?

Comment: did u use the same fitted tokenizer at inference time ?

Comment: Yes I Used the same tokenizer @MarcoCerliani

Comment: no... U clearly don't use the same, since u instantiate a new one and operate a new fit_transform... U have to save the same tokenizer used during fitting and repeat the same preprocessing steps also for unseen data

Comment: I will try and come back to you @MarcoCerliani

Comment: @rgzv is apparently using `fit_transform` just once. The problem may be on the padding type and lack of masking.